# How can I configure Salesforce Essentials such that a particular report becomes the home screen?

Tags: reporting

I'm a Salesforce Essentials user/admin. I have created a report that shows me the specific information I need from day to day. If I'm not interacting with a specific opportunity, 95% of the time I use this report. It's annoying to have to grab it out of the reports dropdown menu every time I want it, especially  since it sometimes moves position.

What I want is that when I click the home button, I get the report. If that isn't possible, the next best option would be to be able to get my report by clicking on the reports tab without having to drill down to it: again, 95% of the time when I want a report, this is the one I want.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this, and searches haven't turned up anything useful. Can anyone help?

By the way, while I'm technically skilled in general, I have very limited experience with Salesforce.

#### Edit

By the way, I want my report to be in tabular form, not chart form.

Answer (score 0):

## Lightning

First, edit your Report to include a Chart, and make sure it's saved in a Public Folder.

Next, go to the Home tab, click on Gear icon (⚙), then Edit Page. Find the Report Chart Standard Component, and add it to the page. Select your Report and any options you want.

Save and Activate this Lightning Record Page. Your Report is now available as a Chart on the Home tab.

## Classic

Edit the Report to include at least one Grouping (ungrouped reports can't be added to a Dashboard).

Click on the Dashboards tab, create a new Dashboard if you don't already have one, edit the Dashboard, and add the Report as a Chart.

Once Saved, you can go back to the Home tab and you'll see the Dashboard, which will include your Report.

---

Either way, once you have it done, your Report is directly visible on the Home tab, and one click away from drilling into the details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, a chart won't show the information I need. I need a table. Earlier, I had created a chart and found it annoying because the information was marginally useful, and I had to scroll down all the time to see what I was actually looking for. Then it took a long time to convince the report to actually stop showing the chart. So, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve a chart.